# Ошибка Hibernate - org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Есть пара Hibernate entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_balance")
public class AccountBalance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_number", nullable = false)
    private Account accountNumber;

    @Column(name = "balance_date", nullable = false)
    private Long balanceDate;

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private Number amount;

    public Long getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}
    public Account getAccountNumber() {return accountNumber;}
    public void setAccountNumber(Account accountNumber) {this.accountNumber = accountNumber;}
    public Long getBalanceDate() {return balanceDate;}
    public void setBalanceDate(Long balanceDate) {this.balanceDate = balanceDate;}
    public Number getAmount() {return amount;}
    public void setAmount(Number amount) {this.amount = amount;}
}
```

и связная с ней

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    private String number;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", nullable = false)
    private Client clientId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    private AccountType accountType;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "currency", nullable = false)
    private Currency currency;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private AccountStatus accountStatus;

    @Column(name = "open_date", nullable = false)
    private Long openDate;

    @Column(name = "close_date")
    private Long closeDate;

    @Column(name = "deferment")
    private Integer deferment;

    public String getNumber() {return number;}
    public void setNumber(String number) {this.number = number;}
    public Client getClientId() {return clientId;}
    public void setClientId(Client clientId) {this.clientId = clientId;}
    public AccountType getAccountType() {return accountType;}
    public void setAccountType(AccountType accountType) {this.accountType = accountType;}
    public Currency getCurrency() {return currency;}
    public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {this.currency = currency;}
    public AccountStatus getAccountStatus() {return accountStatus;}
    public void setAccountStatus(AccountStatus accountStatus) {this.accountStatus = accountStatus;}
    public Long getOpenDate() {return openDate;}
    public void setOpenDate(Long openDate) {this.openDate = openDate;}
    public Long getCloseDate() {return closeDate;}
    public void setCloseDate(Long closeDate) {this.closeDate = closeDate;}
    public Integer getDeferment() {return deferment;}
    public void setDeferment(Integer deferment) {this.deferment = deferment;}

    public enum AccountType {
        PAYMENT,    //расчётный
        BUDGET,     //бюджетный
        TRANSIT,    //транзитный
        OVERDRAFT   //овердрафт
    }

    public enum Currency {
        RUR
    }

    public enum AccountStatus {
        INACTIVE,   //неактивный
        ACTIVE,     //активный
        LOCKED,     //заблокированный
        CLOSED      //закрытый
    }
}
```

Программа по Id клиента находит все его аккаунты.

> HQL - "SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE a.clientId = '123'"

Тут проблем нет. Всё находит прекрасно.
Далее, в цикле для каждого аккаунта ищем его баланс.

> HQL - "SELECT a FROM AccountBalance a WHERE a.accountNumber =
> '12345678'"

И вот тут возникает ошибка

> org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

> cause: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header:
> 31302E35

Подскажите, люди добрые, что он не может десериализовать?
С сущностью Account и Client вроде бы всё в порядке. Их получить могу. Грешу на Number в AccountBalance, но он должен быть сериализуем.

Comment: `Грешу на Number`, ну и поэтому ошибка?

Comment: Ну... замена на Double помогла. Однако это не объясняет, что не так с Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, hibernate не поддерживает тип Number